# Configparser under Kivy

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, configparser, buildozer

I have a problem deploying a Kivy application using configparser

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen

import configparser

class MainFrame(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainFrame, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        pass

    def on_quit_button_click(self):
        quit()


class BasicApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainFrame()
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    BasicApp().run()
```

with the following basic.kv

```
<MainFrame>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'Click to quit ... test'
            on_press: root.on_quit_button_click()
```

It works perfectly on the pc and I can build and deploy on Android using buildozer provided I comment out the line

```
import configparser
```

With that line in the app closes as soon as the splash screen is displayed

my buildozer.spec file is [here](https://pastebin.com/BSPzigvq)

and a copy of the logcat is [here](https://pastebin.com/MYxKSgH2)

[Update 2018.04.26:08:16]

I  have done some debugging and when run on the android device it return an 'import error' at the point that it attempts to load configparser.

[Update 2018.04.26:08:41]
It loads if I use ConfigParser (i.e. the Python 2 version). Is this a bug in configparser (Python 3)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kivy comes with its own [configparser](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.config.html). It appears this is based on the standard python configparser.

Use:

```
from kivy.config import ConfigParser
```

Comment: Able to run the Kivy App on an Acer Android tablet without adding, `from kivy.config import ConfigParser` into Python script. Only added `configparser` to buildozer's requirments, `requirements = kivy, configparser`